# Java Regex Replacement Issue

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code...

```
private static final String REGEX_TEAMSPLIT =
 "([0-9]*)\\s-\\s([A-Z,a-z][a-z,\\s,A-Z]*)";
...
String reg = teamNames.get(0).html();
//reg == '62401 - Breakers'
teamNumber = reg.replace(REGEX_TEAMSPLIT, "$1");
//teamNumber == '62401 - Breakers'
```

Now I was assuming this would leave me with only the first group per what I read online. But as you can see this is not the case. Can someone tell what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). (`replace` method does not interpret the first  parameter as regular expression, but matches literally)

```
String REGEX_TEAMSPLIT = "([0-9]*)\\s-\\s([A-Z,a-z][a-z,\\s,A-Z]*)";
String reg = "62401 - Breakers";
String teamNumber = reg.replaceAll(REGEX_TEAMSPLIT, "$1");
System.out.println(teamNumber); // => 62401
```